# Storing multiple datasets

Tags: database, charts, dataset

I am looking to store multiple datasets in a single database in such a way that different sets can be stored in the same tables, but when the data is pulled out, depending on the data, it can be visualised as a specific chart type (or types).

[This](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/43035d22-cf05-4eb5-b253-8f35d9368b72) is what I have come up with so far.

The idea being that the attribute type would be the axis and the value being the value (so axis label or data value itself)

The datasets are likely to be going into 4 different chart types, column/bar, pie, geo-heatmap and combo, using Google Charts as the front end and therefore the data structure.

Would my DB design work for any particular chart type and a dataset e.g. a dual-y column chart?

Comment: I'm more concerned about how to store the datasets in a way that I'm not relying on a ton of tables